# Spring integration: Using a reference instead of a value as an attribute?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, inversion-of-control

Here's a snippet from what I hope will be an MQTT message driven channel adapter.

What I want is for the "topics" attribute to get the value of presenceTopic.

What do I set the "topics" attribute to to get it to use "presenceTopic" as a reference rather than a value?

```xml
<util:constant id="presenceTopic" static-field="blah blah"/>

<int-mqtt:message-driven-channel-adapter id="mqttInbound"
    channel="inChannel"
    client-id="blah blah"
    url="${MQTT_URL}"
    topics="__??__"
    client-factory="clientFactory"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to study Spring Expression Language and Spring feature to use it during beans initialization:

```
topics="#{presenceTopic}"
```

This is really going to be a reference to the bean.

More info is in the Reference Manual:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions